# Cannot load 3rd party library PapaParse in Aurelia as dependency

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm trying to load the 3rd party library [PapaParse](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse) into my Aurelia application, but can't seem to make it work as a dependency. I've tried every form listed in the [Aurelia docs](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli/6). Instead, I need to add it to my *aurelia.json*'s `bundles.<vendor-bundle>.prepend` section.

I first `npm install papaparse --save` then

### aurelia.json

```
{
  "name": "vendor-bundle.js",
  "prepend": [
    "node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.core.js",
    "node_modules/papaparse/papaparse.js", // Has to go before require.js
    "node_modules/requirejs/require.js"
  ],
  "dependencies": [
    "aurelia-binding",
    "aurelia-bootstrapper",
    //"papaparse" here does not work,
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

But this way creates a global `Papa` variable. I would much rather it be a dependency that I can import.

Any ideas on why it's not working as a standard dependency and what I can do to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your aurelia.json

```
{
  "name": "papaparse",
  "path": "../node_modules/papaparse/",
  "main": "papaparse"
}
```

and import in your class:

```
import PapaParse from 'papaparse';
constructor() {
  //papaparse is ready
  console.log(PapaParse);
}
```

Comment: Ahh, the problem was that I was using `import {Papa} from 'papaparse'` (curly brackets) instead of `import Papa from 'papaparse'` :( thanks @Ricardo

Comment: If others run into this problem, this is a useful read: http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html